# Navigating from App.js to Places.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am a newbie to React.I am playing around with it quite a bit.Now I want to navigate from App.js to Places.js .I agree that it can be done using React-router but I could not yet figure that out successfully. I need help in this regard.Having said this I tried few combinations using HashRouter, Route and Navlink but all efforts were in vain.

Here is my App.js

```
    import {Link,Router} from 'react-router-dom';
    import Places from './Places';
    import React, { Component } from "react";
    import { Card} from 'semantic-ui-react';


    class App extends Component {

    render() {

    return (
    <Router>
      <div className ="ui four stackable two column grid">

     <div className="column">
       <Card
         as = {Link} to = '/Places'
         header='Places'
         description='Click here to get list of places.'
        />
     </div>
```

...

```
     </div>
    </Router>

      );
    }
   }
```

And here is my Places.js

```
 import { Card} from 'semantic-ui-react';
 import axios from 'axios';

  export default class Places extends React.Component {

...
```

Basically I have App.js with 4 UI cards.When I click each one of them it should load the contents of the corresponding js files.Will this qualify as SPA?

Comment: Yes. router is for that purpose. you have to register your routes and give it in your logic

Comment: Where is your code attempting to use react router?

Comment: Might be a duplication of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079081/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To define your routes. You have to import first `react-router`.

In your file app.js, you have to cut the content in another file (grid.js for example). 'App' will be the main container of your application
Then you will create a file routes.js and describe your routes:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';

import App from './components/app';
import Grid from './components/Grid';
import Places from './components/Places';

export default (
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
    <IndexRoute component={Grid} />
    <Route path="places" component={Places} />
  </Route>
);
```

Here, with `IndexRoute`, you say that your default route will load 'Grid' so the list of cards.

Then, in app.js file, you write in your render function `{this.props.children}` where you want to display your elements 'Grid' and 'Places'.

Finally, in your file 'index.js', you will import your routes, and the router:

```
import { Router, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import routes from './routes';
```

And, in the function `ReactDOM.render`,  define your routes:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes} />
, document.querySelector('.container'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle routing by keeping your routes in separate file and handle component rendering from there.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import Places from '../Places.js';

render(
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path='/' component={App}>
     <Route path='/Places' component={Places}></Route>
    </Route>
  </Router>, document.getElementById('app')
);
```

When you'll navigate to '/Places' route, it will render Places component.